# How to suppress errors in shelljs?

Tags: node.js, shelljs

When I run the following code in node:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
var files = shell.ls('-R', './**/foobar');
console.log('Files found:\n' + files.join('\n'));
```

I see this in the output:

```
ls: no such file or directory: ./**/foobar
```

How can I suppress the stderr, keep it from being shown?

Answer (score 7):

Took me a bit to figure this out, but you need to configure shelljs to be silent, like so:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.config.silent = true;
```

From the [README](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#configsilent), this:

> Suppresses all command output if `true`, except for `echo()` calls. Default is `false`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Passing `{silent: true}` to `exec()` doesn't seem to be enough.